# Should we add a `line-following` tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I'm seeing quite some questions regarding line following robots. What do you say we add a specific tag for it? It makes sense for some questions such as [this one](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1728/158) and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tag can be created by simply tagging a question...

I'd have no problem with a tag [line-following](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-following) as long as it is populated with a suitable definition...  I've retagged (most) relevant questions.

Just need someone to write the tag wiki :)

Comment: Done. Adding `line-tracking` as synonym would be good, although I don't seem to have the permission for it.

Comment: @Shahbaz Generally we only need to add tag synonyms if people are mis-tagging things. Since when people type `line` the `line-following` tag will pop up it is more likely that people will just use that rather than creating another, almost identical tag.